# AssertJ Verify List of Objects with a List field is not empty

Tags: assertj

Example:

```
public class Office {
  List<Employee> employee;
}
```

How do I assert that in my `List<Office> offices` there are none with no employees? Is it possible to assert this with one assertion chain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to check that all offices have employee, if so [`allSatisfy`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.12.2/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-) can be used like:

```
assertThat(offices).allSatisfy(office -> {
                              assertThat(office.employee).isNotEmpty();
                            });
```

There is also a `noneSatisfy` assertion available BTW.

Comment: Before you replied, I went with `.doesNotHave(new Condition<>(CollectionUtils::isEmpty, "Empty Employees")`. Is there any reason there's no method that takes in a Predicate? Something like: `.allSatisfy(CollectionUtils::isNotEmpty)` Thanks.

Comment: there is one: `allMatch`

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this via [`allSatisfy` iterable assertion](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-3.6.0-allSatisfy) like shown in the following example:

```
    @Test
    public void assertInnerPropertyInList() {
        List<Office> officesWithEmptyOne = List.of(
                new Office(List.of(new Employee(), new Employee())),
                new Office(List.of(new Employee())),
                new Office(List.of()));

        List<Office> offices = List.of(
                new Office(List.of(new Employee(), new Employee())),
                new Office(List.of(new Employee())));

        // passes
        assertThat(offices).allSatisfy(office -> assertThat(office.getEmployee()).isNotEmpty());

        // fails
        assertThat(officesWithEmptyOne).allSatisfy(office -> assertThat(office.getEmployee()).isNotEmpty());
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Office {
        private List<Employee> employee;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Employee {
    }
```

And you can see that the second assertion fails with the message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting all elements of:
  <[AssertJFeatureTest.Office(employee=[AssertJFeatureTest.Employee(), AssertJFeatureTest.Employee()]),
    AssertJFeatureTest.Office(employee=[AssertJFeatureTest.Employee()]),
    AssertJFeatureTest.Office(employee=[])]>
to satisfy given requirements, but these elements did not:

  <AssertJFeatureTest.Office(employee=[])> 
Expecting actual not to be empty
```

Annotations are coming from Lombok.